# How to pick up the walkie talkie in Walking Dead Season 2: Episode 3?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

I am stuck at the quick time event where Clem has to pick up the walkie talkie. I see two brackets moving towards each other, yet I forgot what to do for those quick time events.

How to pick up the walkie talkie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold for a few seconds, then move up.